# Javascript closure in fibonacci series using dynamic programming

Tags: javascript, closures, fibonacci

I am trying to figure out closure in Javascript.

Trying to calculate fibonacci series using DP.
Here my input will be index: Index = 10
And the output: 55 (As per fibonacci seq: 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55..)

Below version is a working code:

```
function recursiveDynamicProgramming(){
let cache = {};
//use javascript closure method
return function getFib(n){
//var getFib = function(n){ : When i assign function to this variable. I am getting undefined error. Although it has return value :(
    if(n in cache){//if(cache[n])
        return cache[n];
    } else{
        if(n < 2){
            return n;
        }else{
            cache[n] = getFib(n - 2) + getFib(n - 1);
            return cache[n];
        }
    }
}
}  
const dynamicProdFib = recursiveDynamicProgramming();
console.log(dynamicProdFib(10)); //Output = 55, Input = 10
//console.log(dynamicProdFib.getFib(10)); //This should give me the same result as the variable getFib is defined in the program.
```

So here if you can refer the commented code where

```
//var getFib = function(n){ : When i assign function to this variable. I am getting undefined error. 
 Although it has return value //Or we can use this.getFib = function(n)
```

But when i try to call this method I am getting undefined error. Which simply means my function is not returning a value. But i am returning value inside this function.
I am not sure where i am making mistake.

We have several examples of this question but i am not able to wrap my head around this.
Please pardon me for this. Thank you for the help :)

UPDATE:
Thanks @Bergi for pointing my silly mistake.

In my case i am trying to call the output like :

```
dynamicProdFib.getFib(10)
```

so i have to put the output in an object:

```
  return {getFib};
```

Or simply call the output as:

```
return dynamicProdFib(10)
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That you are `return`ing inside the `getFib` function is not enough, the part you were missing is that you also need to `return` the `getFib` function from `recursiveDynamicProgramming`. It might help to introduce a helper variable for that though:

```
function recursiveDynamicProgramming() {
    let cache = {};
    var getFib = function(n) { // or just "function getFib(n) {"
        …
    };
    return getFib;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```